# Is it possible to have multiple servers to deliver push notifications to a windows phone app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

We want to be able to send push notifitactions to our Windows Phone App from different servers with different authenticated webservices.

I read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) .

We want to use an authenticated webservice for which we need a client certificate. 
Is it possible to register multiple client certificates (with the same subject)?

If not, is it possible to use the same Client Certificate on mutiple servers?

Comment: We haven't tried anything so far. I edited the question to be more precise.